# Query is executed with 0 rows affected, but when trying to run directly using the database it works

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have the following Microsoft Access database structure: [image: DataBase structure]

I am trying to create a C# function in the class book: `Return()`, that is used to return the book from the client that borrowed it. This is done by setting a return date on the `borrow` table (is being set to the time the function got called).

Here is the function:

```cs
 public bool Return()
        {
            if (IsFree())
                return false;
            const string SQL = "UPDATE Borrow SET Return_date = @Date WHERE Book_ID = @Id AND Return_date IS NULL";
            conn.Open();
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = SQL;
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
                    {
                        new OleDbParameter("@Id", Id),
                        new OleDbParameter("@Date", DateTime.Now)
                    });
                conn.Close();
            }
            return true;
        }
```

When I run it I get no error, but nothing changes in the database, and trying to get the numbers of rows affected returns `0`.

Other functions that involve the database work fine so it is not the connection string.

When I try to run the query in Microsoft Access it works fine.

what have I done wrong?

Comment: I think that `new OleDbParameter("@Id", Id)` has null in Id when you run it from your code.

Comment: You are not executing the command in the code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the order of the following two lines from:

```
new OleDbParameter("@Id", Id),
new OleDbParameter("@Date", DateTime.Now)
```

To:

```
new OleDbParameter("@Date", DateTime.Now),
new OleDbParameter("@Id", Id)
```

OLE DB does not recognise named parameters, but merely populates the parameters in the order in which they appear in the SQL statement.

Comment: Exactly. Named parameters do not exist in OldDb

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code, and make sure that the Id has some value:

```
        public bool Return()
        {
            if (IsFree())
                return false;
            const string SQL = "UPDATE Borrow SET Return_date = @Date WHERE Book_ID = @Id AND Return_date IS NULL";

            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
               connectionString))
            {
                using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(SQL)) {
                   command.Connection = connection;
                   command.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
                    {
                        new OleDbParameter("@Id", Id),
                        new OleDbParameter("@Date", DateTime.Now)
                    });
                   command.Connection.Open();
                   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

You should not close the connection yourself and it is better to use a new connection each time